How would I calculate the coordinates for the points based on the info on this old map?
I am busy with historical research in South Africa and would like to know how to calculate the coordinates from old maps that I am using for research. I need to use the information on Google Earth?
The general area  for the attached example is ->  32°15'9.36"S 25°32'10.11"E

Additional info that I have managed to obtain.
Datum: Cape Datum (Modified Clarke 1880)
Reference Ellipsoid Modified Clarke 1880
Semi major axis (a) : 6378249.14533
Semi minor axis (b) : 6356514.96672
Inverse flattening (1/f) : 293.4663077
The unit of measure for distance on the map is the Rhynland Rood, where 1 rood = 3.7783 meter = 12.3959974 feet

For at least one of the points A, B, C, D E, or F exact coordinates are needed, "general area" coordinates are not enough.

Plugging the constant offset (x=944,000, y=-13,000) into projfinder.com shows that it's hundreds of kilometers from the reference location in any recognized coordinate reference system. It's likely that these coordinates are relative to some esoteric reference point.

Can you post the entire sheet?

Could you give the location as well, that would help tremendously.

I don't have exact coordinates as the farm has since been consolidated into a larger portion and the original markers have long been removed.

Is there any other information on the sheet detailing the Projection / Datum used. As this is a South African map, I would start with the Cape Lo25, based on the Clark 1880 Datum.
You have the Lo25 coordinates for A,B,C,D,E and F.
I would tabulise the coordinates in Excel with the Offests added. For example A:
Y: -13727.50; X: +944 623.51. That being said, without seeing the full sheet and additional info there might be an additional offset. Usually in Cape system the Longitude is positive or negative depending if the site if east or west of the Longitude of Origin (25 in this case). The Latitude is always negative, but is usually 3 000 000m. So your Latitude value may need to be tweaked as -3 944 623.51 places you VERY far south in the ocean.
Once you have a table of these coordinates and have confirmed any constants / offests need to be added, load them into some GIS Software (QGIS or Arcmap) and set the coordinate system to the Cape Transverse Mercator Lo 25 with Clarke 1880 Datum and plot the points. Again, you may need to switch the X and Y, so eyeball that they fall in the ballpark area you working in. Looking at this example, I think you will definitely need to switch the X and Y coordinates.
Once you have the points in, reproject to WGS84. All you need to do then is add some fields with the new coordinates of the points (There are many examples how to do this depending on the Software you using). As an aside, if you save the reprojected points to a KML or Shapefile, you can load this directly into Google Earth.

https://epsg.org/crs_22285/Cape-Lo25.html  The Lo system uses positive  West (Y) and South (X) axes. ArcGIS has emulation CRS but you have to flip the signs to get East/North axes instead. In ArcGIS, the first column should be called the X coordinates and should have positive values. The 2nd column are Y coordinates and should have negative values.

If I am not mistaken the positive and negative values on the longitude depends on which side of the longitude of origin the coordinate falls. In this case the 25th longitude. Looking at the scan again, it does look like the X is positive. I misread the handwriting. I will update the answer accordingly.
